# Python get output of C executable with just its PID

Tags: python, executable

I want to get the output of a C executable while I can only know the pid of the process running that executable. I looked up online and I could find suggestions of using subprocess module in python to run the process, but I dont have control on how the executable is run.

I could redirect the output to stdout and try and read from there but I dont know how to go about it. Any idea how I could do this or any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: How do you call the C executable? Inside the python script?

Comment: Its run from os.execvpe in python script.

Comment: You picked a low-level way of doing it, would be much easier using the `subprocess` module in the standard library.

Comment: But I dont have an option to change it now :( . Any way you can think I can resolve this ?

Comment: If you can't change the python, then what can you change?

Comment: The C executable code. Note: I have thought about writing the output to a file and then read from there but this is a ugly approach in the given environment and I want to avoid this.